# how to get the data from a json from the web using wininet in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wininet, windows-11

I'm new to C++, I am trying to consume the `ip-api.com` API to fetch a geolocation based on an IP number. But I can't make a request correctly. What can I change in this code to get the JSON response correctly?

```
string GetLocation() {
    DWORD size = 0;
    DWORD wrt;
    LPCWSTR down = L"Downloader";
    string msg = "";

    /*wstring ipConvert(ipAdr().begin(), ipAdr().end());
    LPCWSTR ip = ipConvert.c_str();*/

    string url = "http://ip-api.com/json/168.197.155.244";
    wstring urlConvert(url.begin(), url.end());
    LPCWSTR urlFinal = L"http://ip-api.com/json/168.197.155.244";
    LPCWSTR headers = L"Content-Type: application/json\r\n";


    HINTERNET open = InternetOpen(down, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET connect = InternetConnect(open, urlFinal, NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequest(connect, NULL, urlFinal, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    HttpAddRequestHeaders(request, headers, -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);

    HttpSendRequest(request, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
    InternetQueryDataAvailable(request, &size, 0, 0);
    char* buff = new char[size + 1];
    memset(buff, 0, size + 1);

    InternetReadFile(request, buff, size, &wrt);
    msg += buff;

    InternetCloseHandle(open);
    InternetCloseHandle(connect);
    InternetCloseHandle(request);

    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from your complete lack of any error handling, the main issue with your code is that you can't pass a URL to `InternetConnect()` and `HttpOpenRequest()`, as you are doing.

You need to break up the URL into its constituent pieces (see [`InternetCrackUrl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcrackurlw)) - namely: scheme, hostname, port, and path - and then pass the approach pieces to each function as needed:

- [`InternetConnect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnectw) wants the server's hostname and port (ie `"ip-api.com"` and `"80"`), and the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag when connecting to an HTTPS server.
- `HttpOpenRequest()` wants the resource's path on the server (ie `"/json/168.197.155.244"`).

Alternatively, you can use [`InternetOpenUrl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopenurlw) instead. In which case, you don't need to use `HttpOpenRequest()` and `HttpSendRequest()` at all (and BTW, your use of `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` can be removed completely, as you are not *sending* any data to the server, so there is no need to add a `Content-Type` header to the request). See [Handling Uniform Resource Locators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/handling-uniform-resource-locators) in WinInet's documentation for more details about that.